# Wordpress - Buddypress - does BP theme files get rewritten while updating BP plugin?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

We are using BudyPress for WordPress for a little social network. To get the desired look, we will also have to edit BuddyPress' "theme" files - question for the future - does these files get rewritten when updating the BuddyPress plugin?
(=should or shouldnt I be worried about updating?)

Thanks for your answers, or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the whole plugin is updated so any themes that are packaged with the plugin will be overwritten on upgrade.

The solution is to create a child theme which will live in wp-content/themes/. This directory is safe from future upgrades i.e. Your child theme will be future proof.